# Why dirty injection is necessary even for code within template's scope?

Tags: templates, nim-lang, hygiene

Please consider the following:

```
import options

template tpl[T](a: untyped) : Option[T] =
  var b {.inject.}: T = 4
  a
  none(int)

discard
  tpl[int]:
    echo b
```

This builds and runs and results in output:

> 4

But, if you **remove** the `{.inject.}` pragma, you get:

> ...template/generic instantiation from here
>   Error: undeclared identifier: 'b'

I don't think we can consider the block of code `echo b` foreign to the "insides" of the template since: it's only used expanded withing the template, and: it's passed as an argument, not used outside.

I'm forced to use something dirty and now I've dirtied my global scope to make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this works makes sense. You want to be explicit about what is available inside the code specified by the user.

You can keep your global scope hygienic by using `block`:

```
import options

template tpl[T](a: untyped) : Option[T] =
  block:
    var b {.inject.}: T = 4
    a
    none(int)

discard
  tpl[int]:
    echo b
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that it makes sense. I thought inject was about making stuff public, to the caller's scope. In this case, there is no such need.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning is that the injected names are part of the template's public interface. You don't want the implementation details of the template to leak inside the user code and possibly create naming clashes there, so all variables created inside the template are hidden from the user code by default.

Using `inject` like this is not considered dirty, it's the right thing to do here.